# How can I predict a surprise radroach infestation?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Occasionally, even though I haven't rushed any rooms at all, Radroach infestations will come up by surprise from rooms such as the Storage Room. This often seems to come up without any warning and leaves me having to use up some Stimpaks to heal my dwellers.

**Is there any way to predict when this will happen to prepare immediately?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random disasters happens at a variable frequency; you can't predict them or their type (radroaches, molerats, fire, etc...).

When a disaster starts, your screen will zoom on it, but the only way to be prepared is to always leave some stimpack in your reserve.

By the way, disasters that happens in L3 size 3 rooms are tougher and if your dwellers are not well equipped, they may easily die.
You should level up the bigger rooms only after equipping the dwellers inside with good clothing and weapons.

Answer (score 2):

You prepare for these attacks by isolating your unused rooms.

Make sure there are no rooms beside or below these unused rooms (other than elevator, but no room should be on the other side of the elevator on the same horizontal level).  Any infestations that occur will simply end on its own without spreading.